# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS supported how long?

Tags: 12.04, lts

We are considering purchasing ARM based appliances with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

If we go this route, how long will 12.04 be supported before we are forced to upgrade or repurchase a new appliance?

Based on what I have read, it appears that LTS is for 5 years for both desktop and server (post Ubuntu 12.04), so will LTS then be discontinued April 2017?  (release of 12.04 - April 2012 plus 5 years of LTS)

Comment: care to provide a link to that applicance? it will help makign the answer better.

Answer (score 1):

1. you are never forced to upgrade.
2. you do not need to pay for Ubuntu.

Besides that 12.04.5 is supported until April 2017. Nobody is stopping you from using 12.04 after that date. What does happen is that you will never receive any more updates (normal or security) so you put your system at risk if it is connected to the internet.

If the operating system is hard coded into the appliance you buy I would not worry about the support. The system will not get updated anyways and it is likely someone can hack his way into it.

Answer (score 1):

The release schedule including the End Of Life date for Ubuntu releases can be found [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) This page is updated on a regular basis so the information should change as time goes on and currently has relevant information for Ubuntu release from 4.10 to date. If at any time this is no longer the case please drop me a comment and I will update as necessary.